# Global var value don't change

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, global-variables, return-value

i work on a project that i use a global var named cards in a ionic component (tab2Page). I use a menu in app.component.html, but in this menu i have items with a function. This function, i call that in app.component.ts. But i think it's not change the value of global var. Is it the good method, i used ?

**The function**

```
addNewCardWithDistrict(arrondissement) {
//this.cards = [];
var cardsDistrict = [];
var database = firebase.firestore();
database.collection('Bar').where('arrondissement',"==", arrondissement)
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        cardsDistrict.push(doc.data());
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
//console.log(cardsDistrict);
this.cards = cardsDistrict;
//this.disabledMenu();
```

**app.componenent.html**

```
  <ion-menu side="start" menuId="first" contentId="main" type="overlay">
      <ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar translucent>
          <ion-title>Choix de l'arrondissement</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>
      <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
         <ion-item>
           <ion-menu-button color="primary" (click)="firstComponentFunction(1)">1er</ion-menu-button>
         </ion-item>
         <ion-item>
           <ion-menu-button color="primary" (click)="firstComponentFunction(2)">2ème</ion-menu-button>
         </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

**app.component.ts**

````
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private tab : Tab2Page
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
  firstComponentFunction(number){
    this.tab.addNewCardWithDistrict(number);
   }
}```
````

Comment: `this.cards = cardsDistrict;` must be INSIDE the "then" function: `.then(function(querySnapshot){..here..}`. FTM, in TypeScript use "let" or "constant" to declare a temporal variable

Comment: Using global variables is NOT recommended in Angular apps. Please take a look at the **[Angular docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)** to see how to use services to store variables that will be shared by different pages/components.

Comment: yes I put this in then function but he don't find the property